Help Identify SMD IC Component Marking 9HH or D9HH
I have a circuit board that has come out of android TFT Car Display. I would like to know the part number of the small SOT23-5 integrated circuit chip that is on this board. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me identify this part or link from where I can buy this chip. The chip reads has 9HH or D9HH.


Tip: [Edit] and add the pin count and part number into your question title. Someone might recognise it there.

This question is identical to: Identifying SMD IC chip. If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. It was "closed" in order to allow you to improve it before people try to answer it. Do not create a duplicate question.

You say the marking is 9HH in your question, but there is clearly something written in front. Is it logo? Please take a close-up picture.

When I looked at the picture originally thought the marking was HH6, rather than 9HH. Not sure which is the "correct" orientation - The ultimate SMD marking codes database has some SOT23-5 devices with both markings HH6 and 9HH.

I dont have much knowledge in reading SMD chips.. The chip at the time was swollen and i clicked the picture.. not sure if its a logo or a alphabet. is a 5 legged chip and as per how its read, i read it has logo 9HH

Looks like |09HH or |D9HH where the | is the pin 1 marker.

Yes the vertical bar could be the orientation. It is for Monolithic Power Systems for example https://media.monolithicpower.com/mps_cms_document/t/o/top_marking_format_decoding_rule.pdf

i have received the part today... the part reads has ID9RV... will soon fit and see the outcome

Looks like MPS MP1540D, a 1.3MHz switching regulator boost converter.
This would have marking D9xx where the last two digits are a date code.

The inductors appears to connect between pins 1 and 5, with pin 2 going to what appears to be the GND plane. These match the typical application from the linked datasheet.

Looking at images on well known Chinese marketplaces the marking looks identical.
From the link in the comments by @vivier, the HH would represent week 15 of 2017.

The nearby components D25 and L14 make sense for a boost converter.

Thanks for all of you who have contributed in finding this chip.. truly appreciate it.. i will order this part and give it a try... will keep you posted if it works...
